# Index Out of Bounds Exception when writing QuickSort Algorithm

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm currently writing a modified version of a quick sort algorithm and I'm getting an index out of bounds exception even though my ArrayList input has elements in it.

Hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong...

Here is the error code:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
 4, Size: 4 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)   at> java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)     at
 Lab4.quickSort(Lab4.java:36)   at Lab4.main(Lab4.java:113)
```

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
public void quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> S){
    if(S.size() <= 1) return;

    int middle = (S.size() - 1) / 2;
    int pivot = S.get(middle);
    ArrayList<Integer> L = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //less
    ArrayList<Integer> E = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //equal
    ArrayList<Integer> G = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //greater

    int i = 0;
    while(!S.isEmpty()) {
        int next = S.get(i);
        if(next == pivot) E.add(next);
        else if(next > pivot) G.add(next);
        else if(next < pivot) L.add(next);
        i++;
    }

    quickSort(L);
    quickSort(G);

    S.addAll(L);
    S.addAll(E);
    S.addAll(G);
}
```

The ArrayList I'm currently using to test this method is as follows (Think you might need this part too):

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arr2.add(3);
arr2.add(1);
arr2.add(6);
arr2.add(5);
sort.quickSort(arr2);
System.out.println("\n\nQuickSort (should be sorted): ");
printIntArrayList(arr2);
```

Comment: As you can see from the stack trace, the problem appears in line 36 in file Lab4.java. You access an element beyond the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `S` contains a value `d.isEmpty()` never returns false. So you run in a infinite loop. If i will bigger the `S.size()` you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` if you use the `get()` function.

change:

```
while(!S.isEmpty()) {
```

To:

```
while (i<S.size()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

problem lies in this loop

```
int i = 0;
    while(!S.isEmpty()) {
        int next = S.get(i);
        if(next == pivot) E.add(next);
        else if(next > pivot) G.add(next);
        else if(next < pivot) L.add(next);
        i++;
    }
```

variable 'i' is incrementing without any restriction, you must take care to restrict how much it increments, and also your while loop will not break as you are not removing anything from it

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with this code:

```
int i = 0;
while(!S.isEmpty()) {
    int next = S.get(i);
    if(next == pivot) E.add(next);
    else if(next > pivot) G.add(next);
    else if(next < pivot) L.add(next);
    i++;
}
```

From S, you are not removing the element and hence you will satisfy the condition. And with each iteration, you are increasing the i value and when you try to read n+1th element, you get exception.

You may need to check the bound and loop until then (something like `while (i<S.size())`)?

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that your S is never empty, the fonction get of ArrayList only return the value without rmoving it, what you should do is change you condition in the while with: `while(i<S.size()))` also this not the best way to loop on List instead you may want to iterate on the List: `for (Integer x : S)` and use x ase your element.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your while loop.  You call `!S.isEmpty()` as your boolean expression and then iterate through S.  The fault in this is that S will never be empty, so your method will always go out of bounds once it reaches the end of the list.  Try, instead, to check if the list contains a next item.  I would recommend putting the following at the end of the loop:

```
if(S.get(i+1) == null){
return;
}
```